# The content meaning when calling GitHub API with "Accept: application/vnd.github.diff"

Tags: mime-types, github-api

When calling GitHub API with "Accept: application/vnd.github.diff" for comparing two commits, the following content returns:
"@@ -111,6 +111, 7 @@"
Could you please help explaining the meaning of the four numbers -111, 6, +111, 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s the [hunk header of the unified diff format](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Detailed-Unified.html#Detailed-Unified). The `-111,6` indicates that the hunk contains 6 lines of the original file starting at line 111, and the `+111,7` indicates that it contains 7 lines of the resulting file (after the changes) also starting at line 111.